# Randomly pick characters to make a word

Tags: python, random

lets say I want to make my name goofy with different variations randomly.

i have the name BoA - i could do something like this right?

```
import random
list1=['B', '13', 'ß']
list2=['o', 'ø', 'Ö']
list3=['A', 'Ä', 'Á']
random1=random.randint(0,3)
random2=random.randint(0,3)
random3=random.randint(0,3)
print(list1[random1]+ list2[random2]+ list3[random3])

>> BøÁ
```

is there an easier way for me to do this? I just want to know what all my possibilities are. Also, I do get this error. It works fine if its regular characters, so i'm not sure how to fix that.

```
File "main.py", line 2
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file main.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Thanks !

Comment: A source file is a type of text file. There is no text but encoded text. The reader of a text file must know the encoding the writer used. Python is just saying up until now its guesses have probably been good but now that you added bytes to the file that could represent different characters in different encodings, it has to stop guessing and that you should tell it which encoding you (via your editor) are using. After all, this area of computing should be deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
# coding=utf-8
import random

list1 = ['B', '13', 'ß']
list2 = ['o', 'ø', 'Ö']
list3 = ['A', 'Ä', 'Á']
random1 = random.choice(list1)
random2 = random.choice(list2)
random3 = random.choice(list3)
print(random1 + random2 + random3)
```

**Output**

```
13oÄ
```

Also as mentioned by the error you need to [define the source encoding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/): `# coding=utf-8`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `random.choice`, if you want to make longer words this approach won't really be reasonable though (imagine having to create 9 different variables for a word length 9, etc.), so I would use a for loop:

```
lists = [['B', '13', 'ß'],
         ['o', 'ø', 'Ö'],
         ['A', 'Ä', 'Á']]
word = ''
for lst in lists:
    word += random.choice(lst)
print(word)
```